# What is wrong with my UIColor code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, global, uicolor

I want to make a global UIColor value.

In AppDelegate.m I write

```
UIColor *fontcolor;

fontcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

In MainViewController.m I write

```
extern UIColor *fontcolor;

[cell.textLabel setTextColor: fontcolor];
```

But my app crashes without any log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I'd like to understand why you'd be trying to create a global `UIColor` in your AppDelegate.m, if you could explain more as to why you're doing what you're doing that would be great!

However, in the mean time, an issue with your actual `UIColor` code that I picked up on my travels.

I always build my `UIColor` variables as follows. When it comes to the RGB style anyway.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

The reason for this me doing this is due to the fact that that is how RGB formatting works everywhere else I look. It is a number out of 255.

Now, as for actually creating a global variable of it, I don't see the point in my opinion. If it is solely to set `UILabel` color, there is no point in doing it globally.

Whenever you have a `UILabel` you want to change the color of, I find it very simple to just do the following.

```
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

Where `textLabel` is the main `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell`.

**EDIT**

Just read through some of the comments. I see you are wanting to change the color depending on a user preference. Simply utilise `NSUserDefaults` to achieve this.

The end result would be something like this.

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blue"]) {        
   [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:180.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
} else {
   [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when you want to change your colour to a different one, now you need to go through all of your code and change it in every location.

Comment: Usually when building an application you have a color scheme in mind. If not, then you're building something that is destined to be, well, ugly.

Comment: I aim to combine global UIcolor values with nsnotificationcenter to make changes momentarily depending on the choices in the settings. The only color I want to change is fontcolor of uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to retain that: `[fontcolor retain];`

Then have a look at the cocoa [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). They explain why your fontcolor got deallocated.

Comment: Where should I retain? In appdelegate or mainviewcontroller?

Comment: either you should retain it immediately after creation or instead use the non-autoretained version: [UIColor initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]

Answer (score 0):

If you declared `fontcolor` in appDelegate, just use it via appDelegate:

```
UIColor *clr = [(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] fontColor];
[cell.textLabel setTextColor: clr];
```

Comment: xAppDelegate may not respond to '-fontColor' and Initializer element is not constant, it is the warnings I get after trying your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `textColor` value of `UILabel` can only be set to a non-nil value; setting this property to nil raises an exception.

So I am guessing that your fontColor is not properly initialized in your appDelegate.

Comment: How should I initialize fontcolor properly?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add a category on `UIColor`

E.g.:

```
// UIColor+MyColours.h
@interface UIColor (MyColours)

+ (UIColor *)fontColor;

@end

// UIColor+MyColours.m
@implementation UIColor (MyColours)

+ (UIColor *)fontColor
{
    static UIColor *fontColor = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        fontColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
    });
    return fontColor;
}

@end
```

You can then just use it by doing: `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor fontColor];`

Comment: thanks for help, I havent tried it yet, but I have two different UIColor values, which depends on what font color the user choose in the settings.

Comment: You can either have two methods, one for each colour or implement your picking logic in your `fontColor` method

Comment: I wouldn't create a whole category solely for this purpose. It seems a little overkill.

Comment: assignment to nil is redundant

Comment: second static is redundant

Comment: The nil is a little, the second static isn't.